# Registering RestSharp with Simple Injector

Tags: restsharp, simple-injector

I'm trying to register RestSharp with Simple Injector, but am getting an error saying "For the container to be able to create RestClient it should have only one public constructor: it has 3. See https://simpleinjector.org/one-constructor for more information."

I've looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31405336/register-irestclient-with-different-api-urls-with-simple-injector), but it doesn't talk about how to set up the DI in the Startup.cs Class.

Here is the code I've got in my Startup.cs:

```
container.Register<IRestClient, RestClient>();
```

In my controller, I have the following:

Property Declaration:

```
private IRestClient _restClient;
private string _apiEndpoint = String.Empty;
```

Constructor Code:

```
public SmartSheetController(IApplicationLogicService applicationLogicService, IConfiguration configuration, IRestClient restClient)
        {
    _apiEnvironment = _configuration["Configuration:apiEnvironment"];
    _apiBearerToken =  _configuration["Configuration:apiBearerToken"];
    _restClient = restClient;
    _restClient.BaseUrl = new Uri(_apiSheetEndpoint);
}
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: Your question is currently too broad. Please post the minimal code that reproduces your issue, post the full exception details + stack trace, and point us to the line that throws the exception.

Comment: Hi Steven... Thanks.  I've edited the question.  Is this more helpful?

Comment: The "one constructor" documentation linked in the exception refers to the following blog: https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/p/ctors. Its "Framework types" section describes what you should do.